# vanilla js: SetInterval and progress bar

Tags: javascript, dom

I am starting the project where I am to make a "typing test" where a user types a  word in a certain amount of time. After the 3 seconds, another word from an array will appear and the timer starts over. To get the hang of it I have been trying to work on this 'practice' page where I have been trying to make it so that my progress bar resets at each interval of my repeatThis function (when each new box is created). How can I have a function for the progress bar and a function for the repeat code(make a box or display a word)at the same time and in sync with each other. I am very new to javascript and have yet to learn jquery. thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#progress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#bar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn">start</button>
<button id="btn2">stop</button>
<div id='diva'>showHere

</div>
<div id="progress">
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
<script>

var timer;

var para = document.querySelector('#para');
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
var btnTwo = document.querySelector('#btn2');
var progress = document.querySelector('#progress');
var bar = document.querySelector('#bar');
var timer;
var width = 0;

    
console.log('one');
  //button to begin repeatThis 
btn.onclick = function() {
      timer = setInterval(repeatThis, 2000);
};
 //button to stop repeatThis
btnTwo.onclick =  function() {
    console.log('clearInt');
    clearInterval(timer)}; 

                         
console.log('two');
    
function repeatThis() {
     
     //setInterval(function() { 
     console.log('innerfunction');
     var diva = document.querySelector('#diva');
     var box = document.createElement('div');
     box.classList.add('newBoxes');
     box.style.height = '100px';
     box.style.width = '100px';
     box.style.border = '2px solid black';
     console.log('end');
     diva.appendChild(box);
     console.log('end2');
     showBar();
     
//},3000);
};

    
  //interval bar function to display bar in sync
  //with repeatThis function
   function showBar() {
       
       setIntervalBar = setInterval(frame, 500);
       
       bar.style.backgroundColor = '#4CAF50';
            function frame() {
                
                if (width >= 100) {
                    clearInterval(setIntervalBar);
                } else {
                    width += 25;
                    bar.style.width = width + '%';
                    switch (width) {
                        case 25:
                            bar.style.backgroundColor = '#CFD837';
                                  break;
                        case 50:
                            bar.style.backgroundColor = '#dd9322';
                                    break;
                        case 75:
                            bar.style.backgroundColor = '#dd2222';
                            break;
                    }
                }
                }
            }
   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback into your `setInterval` and execute both functions there.

Like so:

```
setInterval(function() {
  function1()
  function2()
}, 3000)
```